# Why do rake database tasks behave strange when dropping and creating a database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I use rake to drop the development database using

```
rake db:drop
```

It actually deletes the database but it also complains about not knowing the database:

```
Unknown database 'my_development'
/Users/memyselfandi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2/client.rb:67:in `connect'
/Users/memyselfandi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2/client.rb:67:in `initialize'
/Users/memyselfandi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `new'
....
/Users/memyselfandi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Couldn't drop my_development
```

This is strange because the is database does not exist anymore at this time.

Creating the database using

```
rake db:create
```

behaves equally strange

```
my_development already exists
```

But it didn't exist before executing `rake db:create`. I guess there is something wrong with my project but I don't know where to look.

Comment: What is the name of your test database?

Comment: Ah! It's the same. Our database.yml is auto-generated from another config file and so it got the same name as the development database. Thanks much!

Comment: Np.. Glad that it worked :). I've added it as an answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rake `db:create`  creates your development and test databases. If you have the same name for both of them, you will get these errors.